# Julia way to write k-step look ahead function?

Tags: arrays, julia, reinforcement-learning, probability-theory

Suppose I have two arrays representing a probabilistic graph:

```
      2
     / \
1 ->     4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7
     \ /
      3
```

Where the probability of going to state 2 is `0.81` and the probability of going to state 3 is `(1-0.81) = 0.19`. My arrays represent the estimated values of the states as well as the rewards. (**Note:** Each index of the array represents its respective state)

```
V = [0, 3, 8, 2, 1, 2, 0]
R = [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 1]
```

The context doesn't matter so much, it's just to give an idea of where I'm coming from. I need to write a k-step look ahead function where I sum the discounted value of rewards and add it to the estimated value of the kth-state.

I have been able to do this so far by creating separate functions for each step look ahead. **My goal of asking this question is to figure out how to refactor this code so that I don't repeat myself and use idiomatic Julia.**

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
function E₁(R::Array{Float64,1}, V::Array{Float64, 1}, P::Float64)
    V[1] + 0.81*(R[1] + V[2]) + 0.19*(R[2] + V[3])
end

function E₂(R::Array{Float64,1}, V::Array{Float64, 1}, P::Float64)
    V[1] + 0.81*(R[1] + R[3]) + 0.19*(R[2] + R[4]) + V[4]
end

function E₃(R::Array{Float64,1}, V::Array{Float64, 1}, P::Float64)
    V[1] + 0.81*(R[1] + R[3]) + 0.19*(R[2] + R[4]) + R[5] + V[5]
end

.
.
.
```

So on and so forth. It seems that if I was to ignore `E₁()` this would be exceptionally easy to refactor. But because I have to discount the value estimate at two different states, I'm having trouble thinking of a way to generalize this for k-steps.

I think obviously I could write a single function that took an integer as a value and then use a bunch of if-statements but that doesn't seem in the spirit of Julia. Any ideas on how I could refactor this? A closure of some sort? A different data type to store R and V?

Comment: Is this in the context of reinforcement learning? If so, you can add the repective tag for better visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you essentially have a discrete [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Formal_definition).  So the standard way would be to store the graph as its transition matrix:

```
T = zeros(7,7)
T[1,2] = 0.81
T[1,3] = 0.19
T[2,4] = 1
T[3,4] = 1
T[5,4] = 1
T[5,6] = 1
T[6,7] = 1
```

Then you can calculate the probabilities of ending up at each state, given an intial distribution, by multiplying `T'` from the left (because usually, the transition matrix is defined transposedly):

```
julia> T' * [1,0,0,0,0,0,0] # starting from (1)
7-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0 
 0.81
 0.19
 0.0 
 0.0 
 0.0 
 0.0
```

Likewise, the probability of ending up at each state after `k` steps can be calculated by using powers of `T'`:

```
julia> T' * T' * [1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
7-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 1.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
```

Now that you have all probabilities after `k` steps, you can easily calculate expectations as well.  Maybe it pays of to define `T` as a sparse matrix.